# Error creating new Android project with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just created a new project **Android** with **Android Studio** and I have chosen the minimum SDK **9 (Gingerbread)** and the activity `NavigationDrawer Activity`, once chosen and created the project I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\xxx\xxx\.android\build-cache\bd439271136a9bc6f4bc228104359605401bab70\output\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design" to force usage
```

And I have not touched anything or modified anything that has created the Android Studio itself and I have updated the SDK with the latest versions.

Any suggestion?

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happening inside it is. The Library support design using the minimum SDK version 14. So you can't use this library if your app minimumSdk version lower than that.

You should use `com.android.support:design:25.+` to support minSdkVersion 9.

If you use `com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1`. You must use **minSdkVersion 14**

Update your **gradle** like this.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
    minSdkVersion 14      // Update it to 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And if I want to keep the sdk min to 9?

Comment: You should use the older design library 25.0.0 maybe that works. But not sure.

Comment: the older version 25 works and using it i can maintain the min sdk 9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152052/discussion-between-bhuvanesh-bs-and-joacer).

Comment: Put in your answer that to preserve the min sdk to 9 you have to use a lower version, as you said in the comment

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions to eliminate this error, but I don't know which one will be the most correct

**I)** Downloading the version, for this you have to modify the build.gradle using version 25 instead of 26 as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**II)** Using `tools: overrideLibrary`, you have to modify the manifest by adding the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.uv.lisitt.seguros"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design, android.support.v7.appcompat,android.support.graphics.drawable, android.support.v7.recyclerview, android.support.v4, android.support.mediacompat, android.support.fragment, android.support.coreui, android.support.coreutils, android.support.compat"/>

     .....
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" //change 
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
    minSdkVersion 14 //change
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And if I want to keep the sdk min to 9?

Comment: i think sdk-9 does not includes navigation drawer

Comment: you may refer [this](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: I try the version 25 with min sdk 9 and it works fine  with the navigation drawer